# Nginx - Reverse proxy - 404

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Receive 404 error while calling URL - http://10.240.0.133/swagger. Below is the snippet of nginx.conf file, I need to append index.html at end of the URI, so I placed a rewrite rule.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

                server_name localhost;
        server_name 10.240.0.133;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/resources-reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/resources-reverse-error.log;

                location  /swagger {
                    rewrite ^/swagger/index.html break;
            proxy_pass http://52.177.131.103:8082/;
       }

}
```

> When I visited the URL - curl -v http://10.240.0.133/swagger

404 is thrown:-

```
*   Trying 10.240.0.133...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.240.0.133 (10.240.0.133) port 80 (#0)
> GET /swagger HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.240.0.133
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 14:41:50 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host 10.240.0.133 left intact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your rewrite rule is incorrect. It should look more like this.

```
  location  /swagger {
    rewrite ^\/swagger\/?.*?$ /swagger/index.html break;
    proxy_pass http://52.177.131.103:8082/;
  }
```

but I believe this still not correct since you have not a set a `root` directive for this server.

Comment: Thanks It worked without a root directive. Does it generate the redirect URL anywhere in the logs file? It would be good for a debugging purpose.

Comment: That I don't know, I would have to duplicate and I can't at the moment sorry.